# Async await issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

In my controller module I have a function *httpAddNewLaunch* that invokes on POST request:

```
async function httpAddNewLaunch(req, res) {
    let launch = req.body
    addNewLaunch(launch)
    console.log(launch)
    return res.status(201).json(launch)
}
```

AddNewLaunch function:

```
async function addNewLaunch(launch) {
    launch.flightNumber = (await launchesDataBase.findOne({})).flightNumber + 1
    console.log(launch)
    await saveLaunch(launch)
    // launches.set(launch.flightNumber, launch)
}
```

saveLaunch function:

```
async function saveLaunch(launch) {
   await launchesDataBase.findOneAndReplace({
        flightNumber: launch.flightNumber
    }, launch, {
        upsert: true
    })
}
```

When function *httpAddNewLaunch* invokes, it doesn't wait until other functions that it invokes finish(addNewLaunch(launch) -> saveLaunch(launch)), it's just continuing executing, so when I `console.log(launch)` after calling *addNewLaunch(launch)* it logs an object **without flightNumber**.

But then I add `await` before addNewLaunch(launch), it appends flightNumber.

Why does it work that way, if async functions are just functions that return a Promise, but they are executing like normal functions, so they should be executed in order they were invoked, but in my case it doesn't wait and just console.logs(launch) without flightNumber?

Can you please explain where am I wrong:)

Comment: "*just functions that return a Promise, but they are executing like normal functions*" - except when they `await` something, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading about how Promises and `async/await` works. There are a lot of good guides/explanations, which you probably should've gone through before starting to use them.

Basically, JS functions execute statement by statement. The `await` keyword basically puts this on its head: your current function call will "pause" until the given Promise resolves. *And if it rejects, your `await promise` will throw instead.* That's the whole point of an `async` function: being able to "pause the function call" while `await`'ing the fulfillment of another promise.

Comment: I believe using the word "pause", even with quotes, could possibly lead to confusion.

Comment: Suspend? Yield? Not sure what word is the most appropriate.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs "Suspend (execution)" is the correct term here. Yielding is something that a generator function does, although "yield" can also be used as a general synonym for "produce" (in iterators, function calls, expression evaluation etc).

Comment: There's also possible typo: with -> will

Answer (score 2):

An async function essentially returns a promise. So, when you call addNewLaunch(launch) without await, the promise is resolved/rejected but you are not waiting for the response. Add await to "wait" for the promise to end.

```
await addNewLaunch(launch);
```